# how to add project to a started branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, repository

I'm using repo & git (http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html).
I've started a new repo branch for 2 projects:

```
repo start some_new_branch proj1 proj2
```

I've already uploaded some changes to this branch. But now I need to apply another changes to this repo branch, which are in proj3.
How can I add project proj3 to "some_new_branch"?

p.s. I really wouldn't like to create a new branch for 3 projects and merge my old commits into it with "git merge --squash"

Comment: have you tried to simply run `repo start some_new_branch proj3`?

Comment: cool, added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply run `repo start some_new_branch proj3`